# Как лучше всего реализовать динамическое меню с корзиной, как на картинке

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, bootstrap

Как лучше всего реализовать динамическое меню с корзиной, как показано на картинке?

Использую bootstrap. Правильно ли дублировать меню для мобильных? Просто я не понимаю как реализовать меню и форму поиска. С помощью медиа-запросов они сворачиваются в меню, а корзина как то остается. Либо нужно создавать 2 меню. На мобильных устройствах первое меню display none, а второе display block, и наоборот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: Изображений открытых меню на мобильных нет.]

Я так понимаю нужно сделать как по примеру ниже, но чтобы Basket оставался, не дублируя его

```js
    $(function () {
        // Remove Search if user Resets Form or hits Escape!
  $('body, .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button[type="reset"]').on('click keyup', function(event) {
   console.log(event.currentTarget);
   if (event.which == 27 && $('.navbar-collapse form[role="search"]').hasClass('active') ||
    $(event.currentTarget).attr('type') == 'reset') {
    closeSearch();
   }
  });

  function closeSearch() {
            var $form = $('.navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active')
      $form.find('input').val('');
   $form.removeClass('active');
  }

  // Show Search if form is not active // event.preventDefault() is important, this prevents the form from submitting
  $(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse form[role="search"]:not(.active) button[type="submit"]', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var $form = $(this).closest('form'),
    $input = $form.find('input');
   $form.addClass('active');
   $input.focus();

  });
  // ONLY FOR DEMO // Please use $('form').submit(function(event)) to track from submission
  // if your form is ajax remember to call `closeSearch()` to close the search container
  $(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active button[type="submit"]', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var $form = $(this).closest('form'),
    $input = $form.find('input');
   $('#showSearchTerm').text($input.val());
            closeSearch()
  });
    });
```

```css
    body {
  padding: 60px 0px;
 }
 .navbar-collapse {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px !important;
  max-height: 270px;
 }
 .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button,
 .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
  color: rgb(119, 119, 119);
  background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
  border-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
 }
 .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
  padding: 16px 12px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-style: italic;
  color: rgb(160, 160, 160);
  box-shadow: none;
 }
 .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button[type="reset"] {
  display: none;
 }

 @media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
   padding-top: 0px !important;
   padding-right: 38px !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
   width: 38px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button,
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
   padding: 15px 12px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
   font-size: 18pt;
   opacity: 0;
   display: none;            
            height: 50px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active {
   width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active button,
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active input {
   display: table-cell;
   opacity: 1;
  }
     .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active input {
   width: 100%;
  }
 }
  .navbar-text a{
    color: #f68235
  }
  .check{
    background-color: #f68235;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
   <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SH</a>
   </div>
      
      

   <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Women</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Man</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Kids</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Coming soon</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><p class="navbar-text">Hi, Michal (<a href="#">logout</a>)</p></li>
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Basket (4) <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li><button class="check">Checkout</button></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>

    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
         <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </span>
       </button>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
         <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
        </span>
       </button>https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css%22%20integrity=%22sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u
      </span>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
 </nav>
    
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="alert alert-info">
                <strong>Alerts Dont Work on Bootsnipp!</strong> So when you hit enter or submit this form your result will show up in the green box below!
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <strong>Your Result!</strong> <span id="showSearchTerm"></span>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

```
'https://jsfiddle.net/ryzyf319/6/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Дублировать ничего не надо.
Пропиши на моб. устройствах в медиа запросах `display: none` горизонтальном меню и с помощью `jQuery` сделай при клике на гамбургер меню `.toggleClass()`, который будет содержать `display: block` для меню, которое раньше скрыл. Конечно же перепиши стили меню для моб. устройств.

Comment: Это все понятно, но если сделать так, то корзина тоже скроется. Я так понял, что нужно сделать что то на основе этого https://jsfiddle.net/ryzyf319/3/, но чтобы Basket остался.

Comment: Ну, как по мне, поиск вынеси за пределы навигации